# Excel IF Statement Query

Tags: excel, if-statement

Trying to get my head around an IF statement (which generally speaking I'm normaly OK at!)

The example would be
Sheet name 201401_ABC123_XYZ

I bascically want to say if the text after the first _ reads ABC123 then return the value 123 else return 456.

Any help would be appreciated

thanks
Jim

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the conditon in plain words? Do you want to evaluate the sheet name? Can you explain the context? An IF statement normally looks at cells, not sheet names. Or is what you call a "sheet name" a text in a cell? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jim question is not clear enough. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Consider Cell A1 has your text i.e. "201401_ABC123_XYZ"

```
=IF(MID(A1,FIND("_",A1)+1,6)="ABC123","123","456")
```

Here 6 is length of your string you want to search for i.e. "ABC123"
"ABC123" - is your string you want to search for and 123 and 456 is string you want to return as per your question.

Hope this will help.